# Convert text histogram to Image using python

Tags: python

I have a file with such data:

```
0 5 9250 20728 1000 1200 34000

-0.1 -0 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3
```

I need to read it and to create histogram accordingly:
first line bar heigh
second line bins.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import string




x = []
y = []
for line in open('data.csv'):
    values = line.strip(' ').split()
    print(line.strip(' ').split())
    x.append(float(values[0]))
    y.append(float(values[1]))


plt.bar(y, x)
plt.xlabel('slack')
plt.ylabel('traces')
plt.title(r'Histogram of Slack')

# Tweak spacing to prevent clipping of ylabel
plt.savefig('igor.png')
```

in spite of getting histo I get this: 
[image: histogram image]

Comment: hint: did you take a look at x and y after parsing the data file? Do these variables contain the values you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the first line as `(x, y)` values, and then the second line as well. You should read the first line as `x` values only, and the second as `y` values only, like:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import string

with open('barplt.txt') as infile:
    x = [float(value) for value in infile.readline().strip().split()]
    y = [float(value) for value in infile.readline().strip().split()]

plt.bar(y, x, width=0.1)
plt.xlabel('slack')
plt.ylabel('traces')
plt.title(r'Histogram of Slack')

# Tweak spacing to prevent clipping of ylabel
plt.savefig('igor.png')
```

Also, there are 7 bar heights, and only 6 bin positions in your example data (with 2 positions at 0). Unless I've misunderstood what you want.
Note that I have set the bar width to 0.1 explicitly.

[image: Bar plot]